# TypeScript template literal string from nested object

Tags: typescript

I want to get a union of all the keys under `states` in this object type,

I have a nested object of `state` keys. I want to get a union of all these keys under `state` in dot notation.

For example, for this config:

```
type Config = {
initial: string;
states: {
    idle: {
        on: {
          START: string;
        };
    };
    running: {
        on: {
            PAUSE: string;
        };
    };
    paused: {
        initial: string;
        states: {
            frozen: {
                on: {
                    HEAT: string;
                };
            };
        };
        on: {
          RESET: string;
        };
    };
};
```

I want `'idle' | 'running' | 'paused' | 'paused.frozen'`

Is this possible? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the values or a union type? And for this *specific* structure or for any general object with arbitrary nesting? For just this thing you could do `type KeyType = keyof Config.states | keyof Config.states.paused.states;` although that doesn't generalize.

Comment: Yeah, the config object might change, so I need a generic solution for nested `states`

Comment: I doubt you could do that as I'm not sure the Typescript type language supports that sort of recursion but I'd be *fascinated* to be proven wrong! EDIT - I was!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like another job for [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) as well as [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types):

```
type StatesKeys<T> = T extends { states: infer S } ? {
  [K in Extract<keyof S, string>]: K | `${K}.${StatesKeys<S[K]>}`
}[Extract<keyof S, string>] : never

type ConfigStatesKeys = StatesKeys<Config>;
// type ConfigStatesKeys = "idle" | "running" | "paused" | "paused.frozen"
```

`StatesKeys<T>` inspects `T` for its `states` property `S`, and generates for each of its keys `K` the union we want, which is `K` itself, plus the possible concatenation of `K` with a dot and `StatesKeys<S[K]>>`.  That is, we are concatenating each key `K` with any nested keys from `S[K]`.  If there are no nested keys, and `StatesKeys<S[K]>` is `never`, the template literal will also become `never`, so we don't have to special-case it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeBYAKCihQRWBQEMAbALigGdgAnUtAbkOKcuAgfr4ixEgBNqEQVxHFEU4TOIBlACoBBAEor6TVgg7SZAX04KREJEggBjYAAoAlPQBucFKNPHPI5gFcEZPryilByuIaKAApqAKpKAKI6LGzeXhHEFla2ji5uHhEmEWCUvgwQosGKpORUdIzJ+qkiPHwC4WYySMxwAF4QCJUhsgPtQ4oAEvFq2vV6Bh2KhQvESyGrimFCYxrxCTO6KelQ6yveS0aEoJBQSsC8-ADSECAMADwqAHxYUCpQEAAefAQogYuHq9zapCszBuxygAH5RlAANoPEgIKDxQHMSi2V4Aa2ecCQNwANLM2B8ALr0NEAHygAAMACQ4B5GAB0rNuEKeL1eSlRVI+RkZhCMyKxLFxwAJRJJSnJB301Kg9AQEGcEGYhEu4Gg8GQ6B5rT5oOwJsezzehtQaA+pgA9I6oFcDYg7ZaGGbvgAidwSX1QBm+vwBNhBkPFUrlSNQX3RsqiDldXr9X1AA)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a recursive conditional type like this:

```
type StateKeys<T> = T extends {states: infer S}
  ? keyof S | StateKeys<S[keyof S]>
  : never

type Test = StateKeys<Config>
// type Test = "idle" | "running" | "paused" | "frozen"
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKKFBFYFAQwBsAuKAZ2ACdi0BuA%204c4CO2-QoRQATShH4dBURBKlSAygBUAggCVFtBswRtJggL7sphvYwCuCEjtlyZuPVIAKygKryAopqYsjck8d9CMHIzOghhGyliUgoaTm1dOU5uXki5JEY4AC8IBDSkuwEkuQAJd2UNeJ8HP0Damv9bPPtiqFV3D0qtaqTGwkb9PEG8UEgoeS4eAGkIEDoAHkUAPiwoRSgIAA8eBGE6XAYUviJkCEZxwcIAfigAa1m4JHGoAB9xyYgZufn5AG17kCPcYAXSWHFoCAgADczngRuBoIpeMBVhMUl8FvBkOgwQB6XFQUaI5GrABEIjEpNeUFJ5ksLCpb1JwVC4UZNIy2VypKAA)

Ah, I missed that you needed `paused.frozen` instead of just `frozen`. For what it's worth, my old solution could be fixed like this, using just conditional types:

```
type StateKeysForKey<S, K> = K extends keyof S & string
  ? `${K}.${StateKeys<S[K]>}`
  : never

type StateKeys<T> = T extends {states: infer S}
  ? keyof S | StateKeysForKey<S, keyof S>
  : never

type Test = StateKeys<Config>
// type Test = "idle" | "running" | "paused" | "paused.frozen"
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKKFBFYFAQwBsAuKAZ2ACdi0BuA%204c4CO2-QoRQATShH4dBURBKlSAygBUAggCVFtBswRtJggL7sphvYwCuCEjtlyZuPVIAKygKryAopqYsjck8d9CMHIzOghhGyliUgoaTm1dOU5uXki5JEY4AC8IBDSkuwEkuQAJd2UNeJ8HP0Damv9bPPtiqFV3D0qtaqTGwkb9PEG8UEgoeS4eAGkIEDoAMThGGZAAHnkAGigpgD4sbagIAA8eBGE6KABrWbgkcagAMiqdDgB%20KAADABIcKf0AOh%20ExSKzo6wA2lMALo7fQfDi0BAQABuEEYeBG4GgwOmszBij22EUhxOuXOuAYKT4RGQaPGg0I72uIFu9wAPuNJhBQYtlrN1ltmaz5DsEVAkaj0ZixopeMB9jjuXjVvBkOhRQB6DVQUbQWUMfYAIhEYkNUA5hvMlhYZotwVC4VtUEN9rCwn%20GWyuUNQA)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `keyof` keyword, in your particular example one solution could be `keyof states`

Comment: What about the nested states (e.g. frozen)?

Comment: Yeah, that won't cover the nested states